# "symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure"

Tags: sudo, libraries, puppy-linux, nss

I'm in puppy linux (Tahr), installed Discord and tried to run it with

```
sudo discord
```

First the problem was that i didn't have the `libnss3.so` library. Installed it.

Then I needed the `libnssutil3.so` library, installed it too.
Now when I run:

```
sudo discord
```

I get:

```
/usr/share/discord/Discord: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure
```

Answer (score 0):

So, since you're using `puppy linux` (which run everything as root by default, though it does have a user set up named `spot` in latest version, mainly for the application which require non-root permissions), you *do not* need `sudo`:

```bsh
discord
```

Should suffice. Secondly, the error you saw:

```
/usr/share/discord/Discord: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure
```

Happen because of a difference of version, between your local `libnssutil3.so` library, and the one that `discord` require...

You probably have 3 possible fix for this:

- Try the other possible ways to install `discord` (there a appimage if i recall right, some other format/repository like snap, etc).
- Use it in the browser ( I mean, it has more chance of working there, and you usually don't need to install anything else, unless you find it work better in `chromium-based` browser instead).
- Go ask on the [now official](https://forum.puppylinux.com/index.php) puppy linux forum. They're probably more used/apt to answer this than here :)

Comment: Yeah, Discord work without problems in browser but there's others portable apps that don't have a browser version and give me the same error. I'm using the browser version of Discord until find the version of libnssutil3.so required.

Comment: Then may i suggest the other things i mentioned in my answer? :) Maybe try the one in the snap repo, or ask on the official forum i mentioned. Also, an another advice would be to try the latest puppy (fossa) where I'm sure you'd have more luck in making this work (using just the `deb` package) @LautaroLipera